# Parámetros opcionales de ui-router no responde

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Saludos,
Uso ui-router de angular 1.6 y no me reponde el ui-sref el codigo sería

```
.state('app.Varios.Consultas', {
url: '/Varios/Consultas/:targe'

<a ui-sref="app.Varios.Consultas">Consultas</a>
```

En éste caso la ui-sref no se genera, tal vez sea porque espera el targe, pero el targe aqui debería ser opcional, porque deseo que funcione de la dos formas una con targe y la otra sin targe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que tu parámetro sea opcional tienes que usar el signo de interrogación:

`url: '/Varios/Consultas/:targe?'`

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por su respuesta, de hecho funcionaba con ?, por alguna razón ya no lo hace, despues de mucho investigar resolví poniendo la propiedad

params : {
  targe : ''
}

Aquí llegué a la conclución de que si o si ahora espera los parámetros, en este caso como no le paso el parámetro, ui-route se encargará de ponerlo vacío, como lo indiqué.